# Intellj plugin dev：how to read target project‘s file and parse?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

i want to ues intell api read a file(app.properties) from target project and read file content, Which API should I use？ like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?

Comment: Check the SDK: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/virtual-file.html#how-do-i-get-a-virtual-file